# Last argument of Array.Copy & Buffer.BlockCopy

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

```
Array.Copy(sourceArray,targetArray,length);

Buffer.BlockCopy(sourceArray,startInSource,targetArray,startInTarget,Length);
```

Is Length `sourceArray.Length` or `sourceArray.Length * sizeof(type)`?

Where  type is the type of the element in `sourceArray`, e.g. int when source array is integer.

I am getting the expected result when using `sourceArray.Length` but I see innumerable examples using `sourceArray.Length * sizeof(type)`. What am I missing?

Comment: You are not working with bytes to do `sourceArray.Length * sizeof(type)`. thats just a simple copy. when length is 1 it will copy 1 integer which is 4 bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Buffer.BlockCopy` the last argument is `count` and it represents **the number of bytes to copy.**

but the last argument in [Array.Copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4yx47a1(v=vs.110).aspx) is:

> length, Type: System.Int32: A 32-bit integer that represents **the number**
>   **of elements to copy**.

So if you want to copy the whole `sourceArray` into `destinationArray` using `Array.Copy` you should use `sourceArray.Length` and if you have to use `Buffer.BlockCopy` then use `sourceArray.Length * sizeof(type)`.